# How to change drawable source from java file?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

So, I have a button to switch current language. It shows flag and country name next to it [(Flag) ENG] I want to change text and image when user clicks it, so it changes application language and displays current. I know how to change text, but have no clue how to make image change it source

Java file

```
public void LanguageButtonClick(View view)
{
    Button lngBtn = findViewById(R.id.languageButton);

    if(currentLanguage == Languages.English)
    {
        currentLanguage = Languages.Polish;
        lngBtn.setText("pl");
        //Set android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_poland"
    }
    else if (currentLanguage == Languages.Polish)
    {
        currentLanguage = Languages.English;
        lngBtn.setText("eng");
        ///Set android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_united_kingdom"
    }
}
```

xml file

```
<Button
    android:onClick="LanguageButtonClick"
    android:id="@+id/languageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:width="125dp"
    android:height="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/language_button"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_united_kingdom" <------------------This one
    android:text="@string/eng"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
    app:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `setCompoundDrawables`

```java
Drawable drawable = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_united_kingdom);
lngBtn.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null);
```

Here's the full code

```
public void LanguageButtonClick(View view)
{
    Button lngBtn = findViewById(R.id.languageButton);

    if(currentLanguage == Languages.English)
    {
        currentLanguage = Languages.Polish;
        lngBtn.setText("pl");
        Drawable drawable = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_poland);
    lngBtn.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null);
    }
    else if (currentLanguage == Languages.Polish)
    {
        currentLanguage = Languages.English;
        lngBtn.setText("eng");
        Drawable drawable = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_united_kingdom);
    lngBtn.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is *setCompundDrawables* is better than one of the two methods:
1. setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable drawable)
2. setBackgroundResource (int resId)

Comment: it highlights "getContext()" in red and displays "Cannot resolve method getContext in MainActivity" :(

Comment: ok I avoided that error with just 
Drawable drawable = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_united_kingdom);
lngBtn.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null);
I checked that it gets drawable, but setCompoundDrawables doesnt do anything and button displays just "PL" and no image

Comment: 1. setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable drawable) 2. setBackgroundResource (int resId) changes the whole background to Poland Flag, I just want to change an icon to desired flag, not whole button

Comment: Ok I got this, istead of using setCompundDrawables, I used setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds and it worked ^^ thanks for advice!